# Translating math equation as another equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question of the prompt. I thought the answer to be "b-11", but it is not listed as an option, so is there another way to translate the problem? Excuse my lack of correct terms.

---

Read -11 - (-b).
Choose the correct translation for -11 - (-b).

A.  eleven plus b 
B.  negative eleven plus negative b 
C.  negative eleven minus b 
D.  negative eleven minus the opposite of b

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to do any manipulation. Just translate the exact expression $-11-(-b)$ to words, left to right. That being said, even with manipulations, only one of the alternatives give a correct answer, so at least the problem author was nice to you in _that_ respect.

Comment: A, B, C are wrong. That leaves D, though no mathematician would call $-x$ the opposite of $x$.

Comment: @André Nicolas That's pretty common terminology. Martin-Gay, Prealgebra & Introductory Algebra, Sec. 2.1: "The phrase 'the opposite of' is written symbols as '-'". Also Bittinger, Intermediate Algebra Sec. R.1, etc.

Comment: @Jenn: Read the direction carefully. "Translate" is not the same as "simplify". Just read the expression literally in English.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: There are various disconnects between school usage mathematical usage. One that causes a great deal of trouble is $\sqrt{9}=\pm 3$ versus $\sqrt{9}=3$.

Comment: @André Nicolas: $\sqrt{9}$ doesn't ever mean $\pm 3$. The symbol $\sqrt{x}$ is a function that means "the principal square root of x". If you've ever seen it used otherwise, I'd be interested to see where.

Comment: In some school books it does, in particular in a standard text that was being used by most schools feeding into our university. I have forgotten the name.

Answer (score 0):

Summing up comments:

1. [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Opposite+%28mathematics%29) defines opposite of a number as its additive inverse, which here is "$-b$" for $b$.

   Also, I guess you confused between "simplify and translate" to translate.
2. As André Nicolas pointed out; considering all possible simplifications for given expressions, A,B,C are wrong hence D.